# Delete hidden folder using apple script in mac

Tags: applescript-objc

My Application has created ".hungama" folder inside users home directory , i wanted to delete this hidden folder by Apple Script.My normal script is deleting non-hidden folders please help me.

Comment: Post your "normal" script

Answer (score 0):

Use a do shell script for this.

```
do shell script "rm -rf ~/.hungama"
```